# Angular2 doesn't detect changes in Array

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor

I am on an Ionic2 / Angular2 project. There I have a

`*ngFor="let item of items | async | customPipe"`

in my code. The **async** is because `items` is an **`Observable<Item[]>`**. My `customPipe` is working fine on the first run. But when I make any change to one if the items that would filter it out through my `customPipe` it is still shown.

What's the problem? Is the `*ngFor` only run once? Or do I have to force a DOM-update? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456430/ngfor-doesnt-update-data-with-pipe-in-angular2
I'll give it a try... after I read it ..

Answer (score 2):

According to Angular2 pipe docs:

> Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input value (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol) or a changed object reference (Date, Array, Function, Object).
>
> Angular ignores changes within (composite) objects. It won't call a pure pipe if we change an input month, add to an input array, or update an input object property.

**Reason**:

> This may seem restrictive but is is also fast. An object reference check is fast — much faster than a deep check for differences — so Angular can quickly determine if it can skip both the pipe execution and a view update.

So while you change your array or the elements inside the array, the arrays reference doesn't change.

So switching to `.onPush` or triggering the change detection manually might solve your problem.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#pure-and-impure-pipes

Comment: Thanks for the link. I changed my pipe now to `pure: false` and it is working now as expected. Can you please tell me more details about the `.onPush`? What does it and where to put it? Thanks

Comment: @SoS you just put a `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` inside your `@Component` annotation. It tells angular to treat any input as if they're immutable. There're more detailed info on the web of course if you're interested.

Comment: using changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and manually triggering ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges() not work for me

Comment: @teejay can you reproduce it on a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I also stumbled upon the problem of triggering a pure pipe when the array changes.

To let the pure pipe know, that the array changes, we need to pass a new reference of the array. So in the case of items you can try it like this:

```
this.items = changedItems.slice();
```